# How to bind JSON HashMap to the @RequestBody in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to bind this JSON structure

```
{
"male": {
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "Emma",
    "pet": "dog"
},   
"female": {
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "Cilia",
    "pet": "cat"
}
}
```

To java HashMap data structure using spring boot @RequestBody annotation. However, spring boot is not able to bind it, but if i receive the json as string and bind it manually to the HashMap it will succeed. Here is the HashMap

```
public class Tickets {
    
    private HashMap<String, PeopleType> peopleTypes = new HashMap();
}
```

```
public class PeopleType {

    private String id;
    
    private String name;
   
    private String pet;
}
```

Here is the controller

```
@PostMapping("/url")
public ResponseEntity bookTickets(@RequestBody Tickets tickets, HttpSession session) {
...
}
```

I removed all Getters and Setters for brevity

Comment: for some reason the question was truncated, i'm trying to delete it and ask it again

Comment: WOW @Andreas ,It worked! Would you move your comment to answer so that i accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@PostMapping("/url")
public ResponseEntity bookTickets(@RequestBody Map<String, PeopleType> peopleTypes, HttpSession session) {
    Tickets tickets = new Tickets();
    tickets.setPeopleTypes(peopleTypes);
    ...
}
```

**Or** try this:

```
public class Tickets {
    private Map<String, PeopleType> peopleTypes = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addPeopleType(String type, PeopleType peopleType) {
        peopleTypes.put(type, peopleType);
    }
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/url")
public ResponseEntity bookTickets(@RequestBody Tickets tickets, HttpSession session) {
    ...
}
```